# Contact form with reCaptcha

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha, contact-form

I know this may have been submitted before (sorry)
I have basic form, these are the details id like to be sent, however i cannot get the reCaptcha to work with it. I have googled all day, but when i try other peoples code (amending to fit mine) it doesnt seem to work.

I would like: Name, Email, Number, newsletter (yes/no) and recaptcha to be sent/work.

Can someone please give me an idea where i may be going wrong? what i may need to add?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my Form (html)

```
<form method="POST" action="Form_Activation.php">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"       value="" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value=""       placeholder="you@example.com" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number">Number:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="number" id="number" value="" placeholder="Contact         Number" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter       Message.." required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox"/> <b> Subscribe to Newsletter</b>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le2SBQTAAAAADIOrUEPpcEVvR_c0vN9GzQpLg05"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default sendbutton">SEND</button>
        </form>
```

Here is my php (basic)

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //$password = $_POST['password'];

    //$keyy = $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'];


    $msg = "Name: $name\r\n \r\n"; 

    $msg .= "Email: $email\r\n \r\n";

    $msg .= "Number: $number\r\n \r\n"; 

    $msg .= "Message: $message\r\n \r\n"; 

    $recipient = "info@islandwebdesign.co.uk";
    $subject = "New Website Request";
    $mailheaders = "From:$email";
    //$mailheaders .= "Reply-To:$email";
    mail($recipient,$subject,$msg,$mailheaders);
    header("Location: contactus.php?msg=1");
    ?>
```

Comment: i see no recaptcha check in your php

Comment: Which version of recaptcha are you using? V1 or V2?

Comment: cant be much easier than: https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: Version 2. @Rajdeep Paul.

Comment: @Dagon I removed all the tampered with code, as it just didnt work. im hoping someone can fill in the gaps really, as i cannot find anything that works

Comment: the link above works, i use it.

Comment: @dagoon  im so confused!

Comment: @JoeyG Okay, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @rajdeep life saver! iv been making sites for last 2-3 months, really interested but alot to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that you've included the necessary JavaScript resource to render reCAPTCHA widget properly, like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
     <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the reference:

- [Displaying the widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

Now comes to your user's response. The response from the user's captcha challenge can be fetched in three ways. It can be as,

Now comes to your user's response. The response from the user's captcha challenge can be fetched in three ways. It can be as,

- **g-recaptcha-response** - a POST parameter in the submitted form
- **grecaptcha.getResponse(widget_id)** - will provide the response after the user completes the captcha.
- A string argument to the callback function specified in the config object passed to the render method.

Here's the reference:

- [Verifying the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

For your purpose use **g-recaptcha-response** to get the user's response. So your code should be like this:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="Form_Activation.php">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" value="" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="you@example.com" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number">Number:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="number" id="number" value="" placeholder="Contact Number" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Message.." required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox"/> <b> Subscribe to Newsletter</b>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le2SBQTAAAAADIOrUEPpcEVvR_c0vN9GzQpLg05"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default sendbutton">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Add a `name` attribute in your submit button.

**Form_Activation.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'XXXXXXX_Secret-key_XXXXXXX';

        if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            //get verified response data
            $param = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $verifyResponse = file_get_contents($param);
            $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

            if($responseData->success){
                // success

                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $number = $_POST['number'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];

                // so on

            }else{
                // failure
            }

        }

    }

?>
```

Don't forget to add your secret key in `$secret` variable.

Comment: i really suggest you use: https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: Thanks @Rajdeep. What about the checkbox? also do i need "so on / "failure" messages? if so, not sure what to put? Sorry :-/

Comment: my Form_Activation.php page just goes blank.... this is the problem i was having before.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for the link. I'll look into it.

Comment: @JoeyG Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: @JoeyG And `// so on` is just a comment. You have to put rest of your code there.

Comment: @rajdeep doesnt show anything. even when submitting

Comment: @JoeyG Did you add those error reporting lines at the top of your **Form_Activation.php** page?

Comment: @rajdeep Yes directly under <?php

Comment: @JoeyG Blank page means some error has occurred, and if those error reporting lines doesn't show any error, then it's out of our hand now. Is the reCaptcha widget displayed properly?

Comment: @rajdeep Yes its displaying properly, soon as you hit send, just a blank page URL states Form_Activation.php.

Comment: The code i put above seems to work fine, and has done for a while.

Comment: Parse error: parse error in ***/Form_Activation.php on line 44 (which is showing as ?>

Comment: @JoeyG So it comes down to a syntax error. You have the error and the line number, please solve it. I can't assume what's there on line 44.

Comment: @rajdeep thats what i said, the only thing there is the end of PHP tag( ?> )

Comment: @JoeyG Paste the entire code of **Form_Activation.php** on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Jjj6jCp8

Comment: @JoeyG There are 3 syntax errors in your code. Keeping in mind that your `mail()` function will work properly, I've corrected those errors. [Here's your updated code](http://pastebin.com/ePjtHnnf). Now test it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @rajdeep you are a legend! works perfect when you tick the captcha, when you dont it shows blank screen. Im guessing an argument to show a message when not ticked?

Comment: @JoeyG If it works as you had expected then please mark this answer as *accepted*. :)

Comment: I cant im to low rank apparently. Thanks anyway @Rajdeep, much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @JoeyG You can't upvote answers, but you can *accept* answers. [How to accept an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Rajdeep done! sorry for being such a newbie :-)