# Google reCaptcha contact form integration

Tags: php, recaptcha

Hi I have a contact form on my website that I would like to include Google reCaptcha with, I have followed a guide to try and integrate it but I am getting this error message when I try to do a test run on the live form.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function getResponse() in
>   /home/guildina/public_html/contact-form.php on line 20

My contact form is currently looking like this:

```
<?php

$to="contact@guildinator.com";

$subject="Message from the website";

$date=date_default_timezone_set("l, F jS, Y");
$time=date_default_timezone_set("h:i A");

$type=$_REQUEST['type'];
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$subject=$_REQUEST['subject'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];

$msg  = "";
$msg .= "Message sent from website on date:  $date, hour: $time.\n";
$msg .= "Email: $email\n";

if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "")
    alert("You can't proceed!");
else
    alert("Thank you");

if($name == "" && $type == 'contact') {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Please fill the Name field.
    </div>";

} else if($email=="") {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Please fill the Email field.
    </div>";

} else if($message == "" && $type == 'contact') {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Please fill the Message field.
    </div>";

} else {
    mail($to,$subject,$msg,"From:".$email);
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>
        <a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</a>
        <strong>Thank you!</strong>
    </div>";
}

?>
```

I know very little about PHP so sorry if it is something simple to amend. At first I wondered if it was because I needed to specify the function but then noticed there was no $ sign on the code I had copied.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Which version of Google reCaptcha are you using?

Comment: The latest one i think, I only signed up a few days ago, is it v2.0?

Comment: And how are you rendering the reCaptcha? Is it showing correctly? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34559948/5517143) will probably guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Just so you know, `grecaptcha.getResponse()` is not the correct way of capturing reCaptcha response, use `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']`. Please read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request) first.